# Performing authentication via spring security oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I configure oauth2(resource server and auth server) in my spring boot app, but how to perform authentication now? How to use grants which I described in authentication server? 
And how to perform autologin when new user has been registered?

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Inject
        private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Inject
        private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authorize"))
                    .disable()
                    .headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        private static final String CLIENTID = "app";
        private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
        private static final Integer TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = -1;

        @Inject
        private OAuth2AccessTokenRepository oAuth2AccessTokenRepository;

        @Inject
        private OAuth2RefreshTokenRepository oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new MongoDBTokenStore(oAuth2AccessTokenRepository, oAuth2RefreshTokenRepository);
        }

        @Inject
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {

            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient(CLIENTID)
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .secret(PROP_SECRET)
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your authentication service and userdetails service?

Comment: @jorrin, I haven't AuthenticationService and yes, I have userDetailsService. Actually I don't understand and can't find any docs how to access sign in request in this case using spring security oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider
  implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
  throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem()) {

        // use the credentials
        // and authenticate against the third-party system
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
          name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

and register it to your SecurityConfig

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
protected void configure(
  AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

}

Comment: Hmm. But spring security has implemented AuthenticationProvider. Why I can't use it? (When I make basic security(spring security) in my app it used spring authentication provider.

Comment: I haven't one. I didn't implement this. And I got mistake: when I use spring security basic i used authenticationManager. I know that spring security has implementations of AuthenticationProvider. Why I can't use one of it? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html I read here nothing about implementing AuthenticationProvider